# CUDA nvcc compiler setup Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I successfully installed the nvidia driver and toolkit for cuda 5 (but not the samples) on a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 box. The samples failed to install even though I previously ran

> $ sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev

I can't seem to find nvcc. I ran

> $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

nvcc -v reports that the compiler is not found:

> nvcc -V No command 'nvcc' found, did you mean:  Command 'nvlc' from
>   package 'vlc-nox' (universe) nvcc: command not found

The getting started guide hasn't been of much help here: 
 http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html

What's going on here? Do I need to install the gpu computing sdk samples to get nvcc? :/

Comment: PATH seem to be missing from your checklist of settings: /usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin should be in there somewhere...

Comment: that's another thing: even though the toolkit reported a successful install, I HAVE NO BIN FOLDER! cuda-5.0 has lib, lib64, and an empty samples folder.

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 is not officially [a supported linux distro for cuda 5.0](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#linux)

Comment: @RobertCrovella: yes, but people have successfully installed it. Look at this http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/installing-cuda-5-on-ubuntu-12-04/ and this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVUOxnpY2UA

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I can confirm that it runs under ubuntu 12.04. But you have to do more settings by your own, like adding the bin and lib path manual. But at least nsight eclipse edition should work immediately. But of course there can be any problems because it's not official supportet.

Answer (score 2):

Consider installing CUDA 5.5 in Ubuntu 12.04. The 5.5 release has special leverages to install it as a debian package. See the following links,

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cudacasts-episode-5-install-cuda-55-linux-package-manager

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

It is truly much easier than all that you have tried till now ! personal experience ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Failing to install samples is a common problem as outlines in https://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/installing-cuda-5-on-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-869

The solution is to find "libglut.so" and create a soft-link to it under /usr/lib. Then re-run the cuda*.run and choose to install only the samples.

```
sudo find /usr -name libglut\*

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so

sudo ./cuda*.run #when prompted only install samples. ie do not install drivers and toolkit.
```

works for me on ubuntu 12.04 hope it works for you too

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem during the installation, but I found the `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so` is useless. My solution is to install freeglut3 first:

```
`sudo apt-get install freeglut3`
```

then use:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so`

After this, CUDA sample is successfully installed.