# cuda toolkit 5.0 installer does not create nvcc bin

Tags: cuda, toolkit, nvcc

I am trying to install CUDA Toolkit 5.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. I followed all the tutorials around and I cannot seem to find my problem anywhere.

I am doing all that needs to be done (shutting down lightdm, creating a symlink to libglut, exporting the paths..., like in http://ubuntuxtreme.com/howto/how-to-install-cuda-5-0-toolkit-in-ubuntu/ or other similar tutorials), and I successfully installed the NVIDIA driver:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:26:46 PDT 2013
GCC version:  gcc version 4.6.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-1ubuntu1~12.04)
```

The installer is presumably successful (at least that is what it prints out) when it comes to the Toolkit, but not the samples. And when I check the installation directory, all the files (includes, libraries and samples) are there, except the \bin directory which should have contained "nvcc". Furthermore, "nvcc" is nowhere to be found on the partition.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not the only one to [observe this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998834/cuda-nvcc-compiler-setup-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Indeed. I checked for the proposed solution, but I haven't realized that the question was the same. Thank you for pointing that out.